# UITableView beginUpdate/endUpdate causing scroll to top

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I've been trying to get my head around this all-too common problem of a expanding `UITextView` inside a growing `UITableViewCell` of a `UITableView` and I'm nearly there except for one small thing.

I have a `UITableView` that has a custom `UITableViewCell`. My `UITableView` is using the new iOS8 self-sizing dynamic cell height with the help of `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight` and `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`, that grows the cell height based on it's ContentView's auto-layout.

I can properly grow my `UITextField`'s frame and my `UITableView`'s cell height does indeed grow, but every time I called `self.tableView beginUpdates` and the matching `endUpdates`, my entire scroll view of the tableView forces a scroll to the top of the table view. I have a method that scrolls to the caret position, but as you can imagine, every time a new line is created in the UITextView, the UITableView scrolls to the very top and then to the caret position and it's janky as hell.

Anyone have any ideas? I can provide a video if necessary. Cheers,
Mike

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jerky Scrolling After Updating UITableViewCell in place with UITableViewAutomaticDimension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27996438/jerky-scrolling-after-updating-uitableviewcell-in-place-with-uitableviewautomati)

Answer (score 36):

This got me as well, and it looks like `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight` is the problem. When I made the estimate large enough the problem stopped happening.

I added this instead and it's working well so far:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Comment: What's your setup? I made the estimatedRowHeight super large and it still displayed this behaviour. Your code sample doesn't seem to be working for me as well.

Comment: I used a value of 1000 and it worked. I'm apprehensive about using UITableViewAutomaticDimension since that seems to be used to indicate via an actual row height return value (tableView.rowHeight or tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:) that the system should use the estimatedRowHeight to size the cells before autolayout has had a chance to figure the size. Seems that it may work just by coincidence in your case. The value is -1 in the debugger and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: This is f**king unbelievable. Thx.

Comment: It still scrolls to the top occasionally.

Comment: @ZackZhu Have you find a solution?

Comment: Having both identical estimatedHeight and heightForRow methods solved the problem in my case

Comment: Cheers, worked for me. Only seems to be a problem on iOS versions less than iOS 10,

Answer (score 6):

I can't comment on [akiraspeirs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29328646/4078527) answer, but setting the `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight` to the exact height of my cell **before** any resizing happens got rid of the weird scrolling issue. His second solution didn't work in my case.

Comment: After trying all other answers this one helped me!